# How to set up dependencies between two different user scope services in systemd?

Tags: service, redhat, systemd, podman

I am using `systemd` to run Podman containers as services:

- Kafka via `kafka` user and managing service via: `systemctl start/stop --user kafka.service`
- Zookeeper via `zookeeper` user and managing service via: `systemctl start/stop --user zookeeper.service`

Files reside in locations:

- Kafka: `/home/kafka/.config/systemd/user/podman-kafka-pod.service`,
- Zookeeper: `/home/zookeeper/.config/systemd/user/podman-zookeeper-pod.service`.

Both are separate, user-scoped `systemd` services. What I'd like to achieve to set up dependency to Zookeeper from Kafka: restart/start Zookeeper when Kafka is restarted/started. I am not sure if it's possible to define such relations between user-scoped services.

I tried adding:

```
Requires=podman-zookeeper-pod.service
Before=podman-zookeeper-pod.service
```

To Kafka service, but it fails with the following error:

```
$ systemctl restart --user podman-kafka-pod
Failed to restart podman-kafka-pod.service: Unit podman-zookeeper-pod.service not found.
```

Fair enough, because I cannot list Zookeeper service from Kafka user and vice-versa, it's expected I think.

Is it possible to set up dependencies between services being run by different users in `systemd`?

I could not find the answer on SO or in the documentation. Thanks in advance for a reply.